# AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader") on EC2 Amazon Web Services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a *Java WebApp* that uses some **JVM Sandboxing** and it works on my local machine.

Also I can generate fat jar and run like `java -jar my-app.jar` also it works.

I have the policy file:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

And I gave FullEC2Access(from Policies) to my EC2 instance, no luck.

I use Elastic Beanstalk.

When I deploy to Amazon EC2(**t2.medium**) instance, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkCreateClassLoader(SecurityManager.java:611) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCreateClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:274) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.<init>(SecureClassLoader.java:76) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.<init>(URLClassLoader.java:100) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.<init>(DynamicClassLoader.java:41) ~[na:na]
    at clojure.lang.RT$7.run(RT.java:2126) ~[na:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: What is the size of your EC2 instance and available RAM? Can you scale it up to the next higher size and try?

Comment: @helloV type: t2.medium RAM:4GB size: 8GB I think

Comment: `t2.medium` is 4GB. Can you change it to `c4.xlarge` or `m4.xlarge` just to rule out memory.

Answer (score 0):

I created Docker file and provided all needed files and started java process like: `java -Djava.security.policy=example.policy -jar <your jar path>`